# How to use auto increment columns when using PHP Text DB API?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am using this php text database api from [here](http://www.c-worker.ch/txtdbapi/index_eng.php#Lizenz) and I am having trouble with the auto increment column. I have created a database and a table and I can successfully insert into it using

```
$db->executeQuery("CREATE TABLE people (id inc DEFAULT 0, phone_number int)");
$db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people VALUES (0, '123')");
```

But every time I insert, it says the id column is 0. How can I get it to automatically increment it by 1 every time I insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
$db->executeQuery("CREATE TABLE people (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, phone_number int)");
$db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people VALUES ( '123')");
```

Comment: I tried `$db->executeQuery("INSERT INTO people (phone_number) VALUES (123)");` and it worked.